# Debugging partially encrypted software PHP

Tags: php-ide

I am working on partially encrypted software (encrypted with [ionCube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IonCube)). If I use my PHPed dbg debugger along with this, [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) crashes many a times, may be because both the ionCube and [PhpED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpED) database uses zend_extension.

Is there a PHP debugger which will work in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [CodeLobster](http://codelobster.com/). Its debugger probably doesn't use a [Zend Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework) extension.